# Firefox not re-validating static files from child frames

Tags: firefox, caching

I'm working with an application that has an iframe - both the outer html body and the frame require certain javascript and CSS files. To cut down on load times, all these static files have expiry set to a year from now and essentially should be loaded from cache for normal page hits - which is expected behavior in IE8 and FF3.6

However, once I reload/refresh (F5) the page, I expect the browsers to send an 'If-Updated-Since' requests to the server for these files. IE8 sends the requests for all the files used outside as well as within the iframe. But, FF3.6 only sends the requests for files used outside (not for the files used within the iframe, it just loads those from cache!).

The response headers are exactly the same for all files regardless of whether they are in the iframe or not. Is there a reason for this behavior of FF? Any way to avoid it?

Note: I can append version parameters to the source, or add a version folder in the path, etc. But, I want to know if this quirk can be avoided/has a good reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox behaves correctly - the server indicated that the scripts are good for a year so there is no reason to send pointless requests which waste time, bandwidth and server resources. For debugging purposes you can keep the Shift key pressed while clicking the Reload button, it will make sure that all data is refreshed. However, for end users adding the version information to the URL (e.g. `http://example.com/.../script.js?version=1.2.3`) is probably the best solution. This makes sure that the cached version can be used as long as it is valid and the new version is downloaded as soon as you update the script.

Comment: Nope, FF does the correct thing for the files not within the iframe. On F5, I am asking the browser for a refresh, and it does send an 'If-Updated-Since' request for JS and CSS files outside the iframe to see if the files have been updated --- it *should* do this for the iframe contents as well. Ctrl+F5 will not even use 'If-Updated-Since', it will use max-age=0 for Cache-control which will *always* result in new files from the server. But yeah, I've incorporated adding a GET param to the static files source during build -- much like StackOverflow.